# The_content and Preg_replace in loaded Iframe

Tags: functions, filters, the-content, customization, iframe

## The Problem:

I try delete the tag generates by a iframe after is loaded.

The iframe is for load a video but then it loads some tags like this `<div role="contentinfo" class="dmp_VideoInfo dmp_is-hidden" aria-hidden="true">` **the which I need delete**

## Explain the iframe process

I've inserted this frame in my post:

```
<iframe width="480" height="270" frameborder="0" src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x68s7j8?autoPlay=0&amp;logo=0&amp;related=0&amp;social=0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

Then that the video is loaded, it create a **divs** with a text 
I want remove the div with all text.

```
<div role="contentinfo" class="dmp_VideoInfo"><h1 class="dmp_VideoInfo-title dmp_u-cf"><a class="dmp_VideoInfo-title-text dmp_VideoInfo-item" aria-label="Video title: MORE TEXT with TITLE xD" href="http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xxxxxx" target="_blank">VIDEO NAME TEXT #text</a></h1><h3 class="dmp_VideoInfo-duration"><span class="dmp_VideoInfo-duration-text dmp_VideoInfo-item dmp_cursor-default" aria-label="Video duration: 11 minutes, 25 seconds" href="#">TOTAL TIME</span></h3><h2 class="dmp_VideoInfo-owner"><a class="dmp_VideoInfo-owner-text dmp_VideoInfo-item" aria-label="Video owner: Ownername xDD" href="http://www.dailymotion.com/myuser" target="_blank">Ownername xDD</a></h2></div>
```

## What I've tried?

I've used **DOM** and **preg_replace** function, with a code like this (in functions.php):

```
function antiponchada($content) {
    if (is_single()){
        $object = new DOMDocument();
        $object->LoadHTML($content);
        $xpathobj= new DOMXPath($object);
        $result=$xpathobj->query('div[@class="dmp_VideoInfo"]'); //example only
        foreach($result as $node){
            $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
        }
        return $object->saveHTML();
    }
    else {
        return $content;
    }
}
add_filter("the_content", "antiponchada", 999); // also without 999
```

and also (the regex is nice, relax.):

```
function antiponchada($content) {
    if (is_single()){

        $newcontent = preg_replace('/<div role="contentinfo" class="dmp_VideoInfo dmp_is-hidden" aria-hidden="true">.+<\/div>/',"",$content);
        return $newcontent;
    }
    else {
        return $content;
    }
}

add_filter("the_content", "antiponchada", 999);
```

## What I need?:

I need delete the tags generated after of load the video of the iframe

Comment: Is this "div" in the content ? look what is in this variable with `var_dump($content);` e.g.

Comment: @mmm I've edited the post for explain better. Please reload. I want delete a div because contain a text with a link (to the server where I upload the video)

Comment: you cant manipulate the html inside the iframe if its third party iframe..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, it's as simple as that.

### Why Not?

First of all, because the `DIV` is not part of your content. It's either generated by WordPress' filters, or the browser itself. So, you can't do `preg_replace` on something that doesn't exist.

Secondly, there's a matter of cross-domain policy. It's not possible to manipulate the content of an `iframe` unless the two webpages belong to the same domain. Anything else, and you will get a security error. This is intentional, and to prevent acts such as spoofing.

For further information, take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) link.